# How do I implement frameForAlignmentRect:/alignmentRectForFrame: such that the frame outside the alignment rect encapsulates those of subviews?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nsview

So I now have my Auto Layout-based container working, for the most part. On 10.8 (I need to run on 10.7 and newer), I see this:

[image: Image 1]

Notice how the sides of the NSProgressIndicator and NSPopUpButton are clipped.

After some experimentation, I found that overriding `alignmentRectInsets` and returning 50 pixels of insets on all sides shows no clipping:

[image: Image 2]

In both cases, the controls are bound to the left and right edges of the container view alignment rect with `H:|[view]|`. I imagine this will happen on other versions of OS X too, but it's most noticeable here (and as of writing I only have access to 10.8 and 10.10 installs).

Now, using alignment rect insets of 50 pixels on each side sounds wrong. I don't think there'd be any control that would need more than 50 pixels, but I'd rather do these correctly. So my question is: How do I implement the `alignmentRectForFrame:` and `frameForAlignmentRect:` selectors to properly account for the frames and alignment rects of the subviews?

Right now, I'm thinking to force a layout and then observe the frames and alignment rects of each subview, assuming that alignment rect (0, 0) of my last subview (the subviews are arranged linearly) will be at alignment rect (0, 0) of the container view. But I'm not sure if this approach is sufficient to handle all cases, and I'm not sure if I can invert the operation in the same way that these two selectors require. Subtraction, maybe?

If what I described above is the solution, could I do that with `alignmentRectInsets`, or must the insets returned by that method never change during the lifetime of the view?

Or is the second screenshot showing a scenario that Interface Builder won't reproduce, and thus I assume is "wrong" from a guidelines standpoint?

In the sample program below, start without a command-line argument to simulate the first screenshot, and start with an argument to simulate the second screenshot. Check the Spaced checkbox to add spacing to the views.

Thanks!

```
// 17 august 2015
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

BOOL useInsets = NO;

@interface ContainerView : NSView
@end

@implementation ContainerView

- (NSEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets
{
    if (useInsets)
        return NSEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
    return [super alignmentRectInsets];
}

@end

NSWindow *mainwin;
NSView *containerView;
NSProgressIndicator *progressbar;
NSPopUpButton *popupbutton;
NSButton *checkbox;

void addConstraints(NSView *view, NSString *constraint, NSDictionary *views)
{
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraint
        options:0
        metrics:nil
        views:views];
    [view addConstraints:constraints];
}

void relayout(BOOL spaced)
{
    [containerView removeConstraints:[containerView constraints]];
    NSDictionary *views = @{
        @"pbar":        progressbar,
        @"pbutton": popupbutton,
        @"checkbox":    checkbox,
    };
    NSString *vconstraint = @"V:|[pbar][pbutton][checkbox]|";
    if (spaced)
        vconstraint = @"V:|[pbar]-[pbutton]-[checkbox]|";
    addConstraints(containerView, vconstraint, views);
    addConstraints(containerView, @"H:|[pbar]|", views);
    addConstraints(containerView, @"H:|[pbutton]|", views);
    addConstraints(containerView, @"H:|[checkbox]|", views);

    NSView *contentView = [mainwin contentView];
    [contentView removeConstraints:[contentView constraints]];
    NSString *base = @":|[view]|";
    if (spaced)
        base = @":|-[view]-|";
    views = @{
        @"view":        containerView,
    };
    addConstraints(contentView, [@"H" stringByAppendingString:base], views);
    addConstraints(contentView, [@"V" stringByAppendingString:base], views);
}

@interface appDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
@end

@implementation appDelegate

- (IBAction)onChecked:(id)sender
{
    relayout([checkbox state] == NSOnState);
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)note
{
    mainwin = [[NSWindow alloc]
        initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 320, 240)
        styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:YES];
    NSView *contentView = [mainwin contentView];

    containerView = [[ContainerView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [containerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    progressbar = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [progressbar setControlSize:NSRegularControlSize];
    [progressbar setBezeled:YES];
    [progressbar setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle];
    [progressbar setIndeterminate:NO];
    [progressbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [containerView addSubview:progressbar];

    popupbutton = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [popupbutton setPreferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
    NSPopUpButtonCell *pbcell = (NSPopUpButtonCell *) [popupbutton cell];
    [pbcell setArrowPosition:NSPopUpArrowAtBottom];
    [popupbutton addItemWithTitle:@"Item 1"];
    [popupbutton addItemWithTitle:@"Item 2"];
    [popupbutton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [containerView addSubview:popupbutton];

    checkbox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [checkbox setTitle:@"Spaced"];
    [checkbox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [checkbox setBordered:NO];
    [checkbox setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize]]];
    [checkbox setTarget:self];
    [checkbox setAction:@selector(onChecked:)];
    [checkbox setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [containerView addSubview:checkbox];

    [contentView addSubview:containerView];
    relayout(NO);

    [mainwin cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20, 20)];
    [mainwin makeKeyAndOrderFront:mainwin];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)app
{
    return YES;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    useInsets = (argc > 1);

    NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [app setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    [app setDelegate:[appDelegate new]];
    [app run];
    return 0;
}
```